# How to override Apache ErrorLog for a VirtualHost

Tags: php, apache, docker, virtualhost, error-logging

I would like to direct Apache error output to `/proc/self/fd/1` in a `VirtualHost` block, but it continues to output to the file configured in `apache2.conf` (`error.log`).

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot /data/frontend/web/
  RewriteEngine On
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory /data/frontend/web/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/1
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

I tried using a file to troubleshoot (`ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/verrors.log`) and I see that Apache creates the file `verrors.log` but it remains empty and the `error.log` file gets the log messages.

Other configuration in `vhost.conf` works as expected, even the `CustomLog` directive.

Comment: Did you reload / restart Apache after making changes?

Comment: @Phil, yes, I'm using Docker and do a `kill` and `run` after each change.